# Rig is hidden in Weight Paint?

Tags: animation, weight-painting

I have this rig Rigify made for me and this model I made, but when Im weight painting, the rig is hidden for some reason. Heres some pictures to explain my predicament.

[image]

Thats what the rig is supposed to be, but in weight painting it's gone:

[image]

Where has it gone? :o

Comment: In the second picture, I can still see the bone next to the right arm I think, outlined in black. Do you have X-ray turned on for the armature object?

Comment: Ah! The xRay was the problem! I feel a bit dumb now aha thank you!

Comment: Cool. : ) I'll put it in an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your armature (and any object actually) show through any object in any mode, turn on X-ray mode. You can do this by selecting the object and going to the Properties panel -> Object -> Display Panel.

[image]

Interestingly, for the armature specifically, you can also turn on X-ray, by going to the Properties panel -> Data -> Display.

[image]